# Where to find Tara gum?

Tags: ingredient-selection, shopping

I'm looking for a source for "tara gum" powder. It is used like xanthan and guar gum, but reportedly
increases the general benefits and adds a "creamy" taste. The only providers I have located only sell in mass quantities.

I am a care giver for a man with dysphagia(difficulty swallowing) and he can only eat a few items
that I freeze with the gums added. All other nutrients/medication are taken in via stomach tube.

I'v read online that "possibly" one of the major ice cream makers uses tara gum.

Comment: I actually use tara gum regularly. Our supplier is [Gum Tech](http://www.gumtech.com/products/hydrofi.php) who normally only sells in very large quantities, but you can probably order a sample from them? (Samples tend to be about 4oz). Their Hydro-Fi TGC-1110 is what I use. It's mostly tara gum with a bit of citrus fiber.

Comment: following sourd'oh's comment, maybe you can look for an artisan bakery in your vicinity, go to them, explain the problem and ask them if as an exception, they will sell you a small quantity of their gum?

Comment: As for major ice cream makers, Bryers, after the Good Humor takeover (ie, currently) use tara gum in some products that were "gum free" in the old days. The "Natural Vanilla" is one example I can be sure of.

Answer (score 1):

They have it on major electronic marketplaces like Alibaba and Amazon. The amounts can be household-friendly, e.g. by the kilo (2.2 pounds).